# How to properly install COLMAP on ubuntu when using a conda environment?

Tags: linux, debugging, conda

The issue is I want to use colmap on a set of images, but am not sure the proper way to go about it in linux in this particular circumstance; colmap works fine in another conda environment, but I don't understand the differences, and am uncertain what my problems are due to. I am asking (please) for clarity in understanding how to approach this, or solutions if you happen to have one.

I have tried two ways of installing colmap, colmap's offical linux instillation guide, https://colmap.github.io/install.html, and by running sudo apt install colmap.When doing a simple sudo apt install, everything generally works, but with the code I am trying to use I run into an error where the feature matching fails (EX1).

However, when I uninstall this colmap and try doing it via the other method, it fails at "cmake .. ", which to solve this I have tried specifying my gcc and g++ (CC=/usr/bin/gcc-8 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-9 cmake ..) but this had no effect. The error in this case was a long list of errors similar to (EX2), which seems to indicate an issue with my cuda. Cuda works fine with me normally in base, but I am wondering if maybe being in a conda environment (which I am installing colmap in) would effect its ability to link to targets?

Something else I had heard is that the precompiled version of colmap won't work on linux, so it is neccesary to follow the method in colmap's linux guide rather than doing sudo apt install colmap, but I am confused on that.

I'm very new to linux so generally any advice on how to approach solving this would be helpful!

```
EX1)
`Exhaustive feature matching
==============================================================================

Shader not supported by your hardware!
ERROR: SiftGPU not fully supported
ERROR: SiftGPU not fully supported
==== running: mkdir colmap_sparse
==== running: colmap mapper --database_path colmap.db --image_path "images" --output_path colmap_sparse

==============================================================================
Loading database
==============================================================================

Loading cameras... 1 in 0.000s
Loading matches... 0 in 0.000s
Loading images... 10 in 0.000s (connected 0)
Building correspondence graph... in 0.000s (ignored 0)

Elapsed time: 0.000 [minutes]

WARNING: No images with matches found in the database.
`
------------------------------------------------
`
**EX2)**

`CMake Error at cmake/CMakeHelper.cmake:121 (add_library):
  Target "colmap" links to target "CUDA::cudart" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/CMakeLists.txt:65 (COLMAP_ADD_STATIC_LIBRARY)`


OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LT
GPU: RTX A2000
Cuda: 11.8
```

Comment: Everything in Conda is precompiled and that works because it brings nearly all the requisite libraries with it. Basically, `conda create -n colmap -c conda-forge colmap` should quickly get a working version installed from scratch without any need to reach for `sudo...`. However, I don't use this particular software, and Conda Forge relies on end-users reporting problems. So if that Conda command doesn't install a functional `colmap` out-of-the-box, then please [report the problem to the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/colmap-feedstock/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue).

Comment: I see, it installed a functional colmap using conda in terms of its gui working, but the issue came when trying to use it with the code im trying to run

Comment: I tried both creating a conda environment for colmap like you suggestd, as well as conda installing colmap into the conda environment I had set up for the codebase I am working with (instant-ngp), both gave me the same error